# How do I use same function several times in html with same class?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm having trouble using same function twice(or more) in html. I'm using class tag as you can see below and handNextButtonClick() function works only once. How can i use this function several times ? I'll post my html and javascript code below.

```
            <section >
            how many times do you want to buy on scale? 
              <input type = "number" style = "height : 20px ; width: 50px; " class = "scale-count" /> 
            
            <button type = "button"  onclick = "handleNextButtonClick()" style = "padding : 4px 
            19px;">
            Next
            </button>
            <div class = "question-two"> </div>
            
             how many times do you want to buy on scale? 
            <input type = "number" style = "height : 20px ; width: 50px; " class = "scale-count" /> 
          
          <button type = "button"  onclick = "handleNextButtonClick()" style = "padding : 4px 19px;">
          Next
          </button>
          <div class = "question-two"> </div>
        
          </section>


        
        function getNumberOfScales(){
        const temp = parseInt(document.querySelector(".scale-count").value);
        const numberOfScales = isNaN(temp) || temp<0 ? 0 : temp;
        return numberOfScales; }
          
       
        function rowGenerator(index){
        return `
        <div class = "row" data-index = "${index}">
        &nbsp &nbsp  Price ${index} : &nbsp <input class = "price" style = "height : 30px ; width: 
        50px;"  
        data-index = "${index}" type = "number" /> &nbsp Count : &nbsp
        <input class = "count" style = "height : 30px ; width: 50px;" data-index = "${index}" type = 
        "number" />
        </div> `; 
        }

       
       function handleNextButtonClick() {
  
       const numberOfScales = getNumberOfScales(); 
       const questionTwo = document.querySelector(".question-two");
       let stringBuffer = " ";
       for (let index=1; index<=numberOfScales; index++){
          stringBuffer += rowGenerator(index); 
       }
       questionTwo.innerHTML = stringBuffer; 
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is essentially due to a bit of ambiguity.  When you call a method and try to read/update the values in your controls (text boxes etc.) you need to be able to specifically identify the controls you are dealing with.

In your code you have two inputs, each of which are "identified" by the class "scale-count".  When you try to retrieve the value from each value you do a css search (querySelector) call looking for a control with that class (i.e. querySelector(".scale-count")).  However you haven't specified which one of those controls you want - so your browser returns the first one it finds.  Because you use the same code for both of your buttons, you get the same result - that is, the first (i.e. question one's) input control.

The same applies for your output - you use ".question-two" for both divs, and that means you get the first with that class and the results end up there.

Sandeep has provided a solution that works - however it uses "relative addressing" to find your controls.  While it works - it can mean that the addition of a new field can cause issues.

There's lots of ways you can fix this issue.  For example you could pass into your "handleNextButtonClick()" method the names (id's) of the elements it needs to deal with (e.g. handleNextButtonClick('txtQuestion1', 'divQuestion1')) - and then you need to name each element (e.g. <input type="number" ... id="txtQuestion1" /> etc.)

However the easiest might be to surround each question with a div, give each div either a unique class or id and then pass the name of the div into your method.  That way for each call you include the wrapping DIV class in your selector to ensure you are getting the control that belongs to the applicable question.

```
<section >
    <div class="Question1">
        how many times do you want to buy on scale? 
        <input type = "number" style = "height : 20px ; width: 50px; " class = "scale-count" /> 

        <button type = "button"  onclick = "handleNextButtonClick('Question1')" style = "padding : 4px 
    19px;">
    Next
    </button>
    <div class = "form-output"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Question2">
    how many times do you want to buy on scale? 
    <input type = "number" style = "height : 20px ; width: 50px; " class = "scale-count" /> 

    <button type = "button"  onclick = "handleNextButtonClick('Question2')" style = "padding : 4px 19px;">
    Next
    </button>
    <div class = "form-output"> </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script>
        
function getNumberOfScales(parent) {
    const temp = parseInt(document.querySelector("." + parent + " .scale-count").value);
    const numberOfScales = isNaN(temp) || temp<0 ? 0 : temp;
    return numberOfScales; 
}
  

function rowGenerator(index){
    return `
        <div class = "row" data-index = "${index}">
        &nbsp &nbsp  Price ${index} : &nbsp <input class = "price" style = "height : 30px ; width: 50px;"  
        data-index = "${index}" type = "number" /> &nbsp Count : &nbsp
        <input class = "count" style = "height : 30px ; width: 50px;" data-index = "${index}" type = 
        "number" />
        </div> `; 
}


function handleNextButtonClick(parent) {

    const numberOfScales = getNumberOfScales(parent); 
    const formOutput = document.querySelector("." + parent + " .form-output");
    let stringBuffer = " ";
    for (let index=1; index<=numberOfScales; index++){
        stringBuffer += rowGenerator(index); 
    }
    formOutput.innerHTML = stringBuffer; 
}
</script>
```

---

This is the code change for your new "getAverage" function.  The *.${parent} * is the key part.

```
        const row_price = document.querySelector(`.${parent} input.price[data-index = '${index}']`).value  ;
        const row_count = document.querySelector(`.${parent} input.count[data-index = '${index}']`).value  ;
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I made another function handleCalculateAverage(parent) as you taught me. It's a function that calculates average , but it only works in section1.   In section2, the calculation is wrong... could you please help me with this? https://jsfiddle.net/Brightsky77/wdv6mbyc/14/    this is my code link. Thank you

Comment: Again you were not searching for your target controls taking into account whether they belong to Question 1 or 2.  Changing the following two lines fixes this:

`const row_price = document.querySelector(`.${parent} input.price[data-index = '${index}']`).value  ;
 const row_count = document.querySelector(`.${parent} input.count[data-index = '${index}']`).value  ;`

**Note** I added the ".${parent} " before your selector.  Without that your code would look at every matching "input.count" - no matter which question they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow!

I took your code and made some improvement to it. here is the updated code

```
     <section >
            how many times do you want to buy on scale? 
              <input type = "number" style = "height : 20px ; width: 50px; " class = "scale-count" /> 
            
            <button type = "button"  onclick = "handleNextButtonClick(this)" style = "padding : 4px 
            19px;">
            Next
            </button>
            <div class = "question-two"> </div>
            
             how many times do you want to buy on scale? 
            <input type = "number" style = "height : 20px ; width: 50px; " class = "scale-count" /> 
          
          <button type = "button"  onclick = "handleNextButtonClick(this)" style = "padding : 4px 19px;">
          Next
          </button>
          <div class = "question-two"> </div>
        
          </section>

// you dont need this function.
 function getNumberOfScales() {
   const temp = parseInt(document.querySelector(".scale-count").value);
   const numberOfScales = isNaN(temp) || temp < 0 ? 0 : temp;
   return numberOfScales;
 }


 function rowGenerator(index) {
   return `
        <div class = "row" data-index = "${index}">
        &nbsp &nbsp  Price ${index} : &nbsp <input class = "price" style = "height : 30px ; width: 
        50px;"  
        data-index = "${index}" type = "number" /> &nbsp Count : &nbsp
        <input class = "count" style = "height : 30px ; width: 50px;" data-index = "${index}" type = 
        "number" />
        </div> `;
 }


 function handleNextButtonClick(btn) {
  // btn object will help you to access other element on the DOM.
   const numberOfScales = btn.previousElementSibling.value < 0 ? 0 : btn.previousElementSibling.value;
   const questionTwo = document.querySelector(".question-two");
   let stringBuffer = " ";
   for (let index = 1; index <= numberOfScales; index++) {
     stringBuffer += rowGenerator(index);
   }
   btn.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = stringBuffer;
 }
```

here is a small [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qecpxw4f/)